# i wanted to use this javascript function with asp update panel, Details are bellow

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

> Here is the script that I am using for opening a new tab and it's working without using an update panel:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openInNewTab() {
        window.document.forms[0].target = '_blank'; 
        setTimeout(function () { window.document.forms[0].target = ''; }, 0);
    }
```

> This is my **.aspx** page: and i want to use it with update panel please help

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnAssign" runat="server" Text="Assign" OnClientClick="SetTarget();" OnClick="btnAssign_Click"/>
     </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel >
```

> i want to use it with update panel please help me if there any solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now i got solution by using a script and onclient click event

```
<script language="javascript">
function PopupHistory(url) {
            var width = 550;
            var height = 300;
            var left = (screen.width - width) / 2;
            var top = (screen.height - height) / 2;
            var params = 'width=' + width + ', height=' + height;
            params += ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left;
            params += ', directories=no';
            params += ', location=no';
            params += ', menubar=no';
            params += ', resizable=no';
            params += ', scrollbars=no';
            params += ', status=no';
            params += ', toolbar=no';
            newwin = window.open(url, 'windowname5', params);
            if (window.focus) { newwin.focus() }
            return false
        }
</script>
```

> on button event

```
<asp:Button ID="btnUnAssign" runat="server" Text="UnAssign" OnClientClick="return PopupHistory('/PatientAssignment/PatientUnAssign.aspx')" OnClick="btnUnAssign_Click" />
```

Comment: [Please use Answers exclusively to answer the question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/92107). You should [edit] your original question to add additional information.

Answer (score 1):

You code would run fine, if you would have noticed that your Javascript code has a syntax error. You are missing a closing `}` to define your function. Without it you are receving an `unexpected end of input error.`
In addition you will not open a new tab until you actually submit your form.

This code will work:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <script>
        function SetTarget() {
            document.forms[0].target = "_blank";
            console.log("Foo");
            document.forms[0].submit();

        }
    </script>
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="btnAssign" runat="server" Text="Assign" OnClientClick="SetTarget();" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: thanks MARCO its working but its not firing on click method, its onlu openning new tab <br/>             <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Assign" OnClientClick="SetTarget(); " OnClick="btnAssign_Click" />

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below script. It will work for you.

```
<script language="javascript">
        function SetTarget() {
            document.forms[0].target = "_blank";
            window.open(this.href);
            alert("hello");
            return false;

        }
    </script>
```

do let me know in case you required any more help.

Comment: hi manoj read update question once again and try to help me out with that

Comment: sure.. i busy right now.. i will look into this after 3 pm IST